# Split large DataFrame into Dataframes containing records of unique values in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

A csv file has 90 million rows. One of the Columns in named "State". It has 12 unique values at present. (The count of unique values in the "State" column is dynamic and can change with each csv file.)

I want to split the DataFrame into smaller chunks and then save State-wise files.
The code below is not working.

```
source_path = "DataJune.txt"
for i,chunk in enumerate(pd.read_csv(source_path, sep = '|',chunksize=1000000)):
    dfs = dict(tuple(chunk.groupby('State')))
    for i, df in dfs.items():
        df = df.append(df)
        df.to_csv("tempcsv/" + i +".csv",sep=",", index = False)
```

Comment: Just to understand more, may I ask if you are trying to split the original csv file based on the State column, in your case, into 12 csv files since you have 12 unique values at present?

Comment: @KevinChoonLiangYew.Yiu are  absolutely correct.

Comment: Are the values are sorted in your file? Like `1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, ...`?

Comment: @Corralien,The State column has strings and the file is not sorted on State column. Other columns have numerical type also.

Comment: Use multiple handlers to write data in each file. You can check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72795986/15239951)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, Try:

```
source_path = "DataJune.txt"

from collections import defaultdict

def def_value():
    return pd.DataFrame()
      
# Defining the dict
d = defaultdict(def_value)

for i,chunk in enumerate(pd.read_csv(source_path, sep = '|',chunksize=2)):
    chunk_states = chunk['State'].unique()
    for state in chunk_states:
        d[state]=d[state].append(chunk[chunk['State']==state])
for i, df in d.items():
    df.to_csv("tempcsv/" + str(i) +".csv",sep=",", index = False)
```

Another version, based on the @Corralien comment:

```
source_path = "DataJune.txt"

for i,chunk in enumerate(pd.read_csv(source_path, sep = '|',chunksize=2)):
    chunk_states = chunk['State'].unique()
    
    for state in chunk_states:
        with open("tempcsv/" + str(state) +".csv",mode='a+') as file:
            for i, row in chunk[chunk['State']==state].iterrows():
                file.write(','.join([str(x) for x in row]))
                file.write('\n')
```

Another version:

```
source_path = "DataJune.txt"
from os.path import exists
import csv

for i,chunk in enumerate(pd.read_csv(source_path, sep = '|',chunksize=2)):
    chunk_states = chunk['State'].unique()
    
    for state in chunk_states:
        path = "tempcsv/" + str(state) +".csv"
        file_exists = exists(path)
        if not file_exists:
            with open(path,newline='',mode='a+') as file:
                writer = csv.writer(file)
                writer.writerow(chunk.columns)
                print(chunk.columns)
        with open(path,newline='',mode='a+') as file:
            writer = csv.writer(file)
            writer.writerows(chunk[chunk['State']==state].values)
```

Comment: `df = df.append(df)`. Are you sure?

Comment: @keramat  The code ran successfully ie without any errors but the files produced by my code and this code are identical and not having the right number of rows for a State. (By "code is not working", I was talking about the size of the split files and not about any errors.)  I think you have changed the "i" in the last row to "str(i)". Any other changes made to the code? The "i" was already a string.

Comment: @user1955215, Sorry, please check the answer now, and let me know the result.

Comment: @keramat. If OP uses chunks, it's probably because he can't load 90 millions of rows in a single dataframe. If he can, there is not problem at all. Another point: `df.append` is deprecated, use `pd.concat` instead.

Comment: @keramet, The revised code is running for quite some time now. Not sure if the "chunksize = 2" is the cause of the problem.  (I have made a small file of less than 4 million rows for testing)

Comment: Good! let me know the process.

Comment: Check the answer again. I added another solution, too.

Comment: @keramat The second solution has been running for quite some time. Is some more code needed to close the files being written?

Comment: What do you mean by  running for quite some time? Actually, No. Because with is a context manger which will close the files.

Comment: Please note that you do not need to use chunk size = 2. I used it for my tests.

Comment: You can try the third approach too.

Comment: @keramat - The third approach seems to work. But header row is missing in the output files.

Comment: Edited the code. Now files contain the columns. Right?

Comment: Thanks a ton for the time and the effort. Solutions 1 and 3 both work. Have changed the chunksize to 1 million rows in both cases. Solution 1 took 51 seconds and Solution 3 took 62 seconds. (I am ok with the time taken by the code.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

source_path = 'DataJune.txt'
fps = {}

for chunk in pd.read_csv(source_path, sep='|', chunksize=1000000, dtype=object):
    for state, df in chunk.groupby('State'):
        # New state, create a new file and write headers
        if state not in fps:
            fps[state] = open(f'tempcsv/{state}.csv', 'w')
            fps[state].write(f"{','.join(df.columns)}{os.linesep}")

        # Write data without headers
        df.to_csv(fps[state], index=False, header=False)

# Close files properly
for fp in fps.values():
    fp.close()
del fps
```

**Update**

Try to replace:

```
# Write data without headers
df.to_csv(fps[state], index=False, header=False)
```

By

```
# Write data without headers
g = (row.strip() for row in df.to_csv(index=False, header=None, sep=',').split(os.linesep) if row)
print(*g, sep=os.linesep, file=fps[state])
```

Comment: There are two issues with the csv files. The header is repeated and there is a blank line between every two lines having data. (The data rows seem to have been filtered correctly.)

Comment: Sorry, I omitted to say. I had modified to "header=True" in the "#Write data without headers" line as I needed headers in the csv files. Not sure whether that is the cause of the double headers in each csv file.

Comment: By restoring the "header=False", the extra header problem is resolved. The intervening blank lines problem remains

Comment: Can you update your post with 10-20 lines of your input file please? Headers are written once when the new state is encountered for the first time.

Comment: If you remove `dtype=object`, does it change something?

Comment: Removed the "dtype=object". The blank intervening lines continue. (Sorry, Will not be able to share the lines from input file because the data is confidential in nature. There dont seem to be any intervening lines in the input file when selected with nrows = 20)

Comment: I updated my answer. Can you check it please?

Comment: Checked. Intervening blank lines are still present.

Comment: What is your OS and where your file comes from?

Comment: My os is Windows. Not sure about the source file OS.

Comment: Just to be sure. If you remove `sep=os.linesep` in the second solution with `print`, does it work?